# Not able to Upload files to the Hosted SharePoint 2010 Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, file-upload

We have a production site where we configured claims mode authentication for dual support

{ FBA | Windows }

```
http://site
```

as a root site with out host header, and two other site collection underneath named as follow were created for the client needs

```
http://p1.com
http://p2.ss.com
```

The problem is users who access the above two host site collection were not able to upload documents to the any document library, it's takes hell out of time to process and returns 404 error... but i tried on the root site @http://site the upload is pretty smooth...

Not sure how to resolve this problem, have modified the web.configs for the uploading larger files also still no luck, please if any one has gone through this, help me resolve this...

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try two things:

1) The file size limit needs to be configured from Central Admin as well (not only web.config). Follow this post: http://angler.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/increase-the-sharepoint-2010-upload-file-size-limit/

2) Increse the connection timeout in IIS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414441/how-to-increase-request-timeout-in-iis7-0

I hope it helps